# SQL Server table with different user profiles

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design, architecture

I am designing my db tables in SQL Server 2005 and have come across a small design/architecture issue... I have my main `Users` table (`username, password, lastlogin,` etc.), but I also need to store 2 different user profiles, i.e. the profile data stored will be different between the two. I've put all the common user data into the `Users` table.

Do I create separate tables for `Consumers` and `Marketers`? And if so, should the primary key in these tables be `[table-name]_UserID` with a 1:1 relationship on `Users_UserID`?

Basically, upon registering, the user will be given the choice to register as a Consumer or Marketer. When a user logs in, the `Users` table will be queried, and their accompanying profile will be queried from either table.

I know this approach is messy, which is why I've come here to ask how best this can be achieved.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Additionally, in the `Users` table I have a `Users_UserType` flag that will allow me to distinguish between users when they log in, hence knowing which *Profile Table* to query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your gut feeling is correct. You want to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data. Using separate tables reduces data duplication, or empty/null columns.

Unfortunantly, with a reverse relationship like this, you won't have a nice clean foreign key from User to Consumer or Marketer because it could be one table or another.

You would want to map a User_Id from the Consumer/Marketers table back to User though.

You could query it in a single query using left joins:

```
Select 
     u.*,
     c.*,
     m.*
     From Users u
        left join Consumers c on c.User_Id = u.ID
        left join Marketers m on m.User_Id = u.ID
     Where
        u.ID = @UserId
```

Comment: Thanks! yes, I definitely have to ensure my tables are normalized. But from a design perspective, would you agree that my approach should be: TABLE1 = `Users` with `User_ID` as PK; TABLE2 = `Consumers` with `User_ID` as PK **and** FK on `Users_UserID`; TABLE3 = `Marketers` with `User_ID` as PK **and** FK on `Users_UserID`

Comment: or should I leave out the FK reference? However, that will mean no referential integrity.

Comment: @maGz: The approach you have described is definitely not unusual. I'd say, that is a typical way of enforcing a 1:1 relationship (which is in fact rather 1:0…1 in this case).

Comment: @Andriy, thanks for confirming that. I'm unsure why I was hesitant on this approach. Could you perhaps confirm this for me please...If I have another table called `Callouts` that references `Marketers_UserID` as a FK, the parent table referenced should be `Marketers_UsersID` and not `Users_UserID`, correct?

Comment: @maGz: Now *that* might be something rarer to come across. At least, I've had no practical experience of defining/maintaining such chaines of dependencies. I can only confirm that I would positively think in that direction if I faced a similar problem. Depending on the complexity of the project, I might also seek more advice on that score from those who have had a real experience of that kind.

Comment: @Andriy, thanks. My thinking is that it _would_ make sense going with that approach. Think about this...by the relationship defined, `Marketers_UserID` can **only** hold a key for 0 or 1 `Users_UserID`. Therefore, semantically speaking and for the purpose I outlined prior to this, a FK reference to `Marketers_UserID` instead of `Users_UserID` would make more sense. I've generated a test model in EntityFramework Designer and it seems to validate without throwing any weird errors. What do you think?

Comment: @maGz: I have no doubt about the approach's sensibleness, I find it absolutely logical. And, if done properly, I wouldn't expect any errors in its performing its job either, though without trying it myself I wasn't 105% sure, so I'm quite satisfied to know you were able to make it work correctly, thanks for sharing. What does concern me most with respect to defining a constraint like this, is whether it can be a considerable impact on performance in the long run. These things shouldn't be worried much about prematurely, but knowing in advance of possible impediments would certainly not hurt.

Comment: @Andriy, I supppose performance would be normal...ordinarily, you would be querying the `Users` table directly or querying against it when using a FK in another table. I'll hardly be querying the `Users` table (only upon login/registering), and instead be querying either `Consumers` or `Marketers` depending. Thanks anyway, it was a really engaging discussion! glad we both got something out of it!

Comment: I've got a license for RedGate's SQL Toolbelt. I'll auto-fill the tables with a few thousand rows of test data to see how it performs. `*_UserID` is a `bigint` so I'm expecting its performance in this regard to be no worse off than any previous application I've developed.